# How to create an index in postgres for query that has ORDER BY on sum of 2 distance and similarity functions

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gis, psql

I have this query which is very slow and I want to optimise:

```
SELECT
    A.id, A.name,
    similarity(A.name, 'some name') AS sim,
    st_distance(coords, ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(24.70674, 43.1379) , 4326), true) AS dst,
FROM Table1 AS A 
WHERE A.coords IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY (
    coords <-> ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(24.70674, 43.1379), 4326)
    +
    (A.name <-> 'some name') * 1000

) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

The point of this query is to get a single row with the closes distance (geographically) but also the closest name similarity. The `*1000` is needed to increase the weight on the similarity score. (since its between 0 and 1, while geographical distances are orders of magnitude larger).

This is taking more than 3 seconds to run. It is not using any index. I created an index `coords` and an index on `name` but they are not being used. I also tried an multi colum GIST index on both `coords` and `name` but also no luck.

I am not sure if an index can be used to optimise querying with an ORDER BY like `( distance + similarity * 1000)`

This is the current `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:

```
Limit  (cost=52261.71..52525.48 rows=10 width=80) (actual time=3029.807..3058.239 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=52261.71..1818549.36 rows=66964 width=80) (actual time=3029.672..3058.033 rows=10 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Result  (cost=51261.69..973104.85 rows=33482 width=80) (actual time=2848.761..2850.012 rows=7 loops=3)
               ->  Sort  (cost=51261.69..51345.39 rows=33482 width=72) (actual time=2607.308..2607.340 rows=7 loops=3)
                     Sort Key: (((coords <-> '0101000020E61000005E8A824B8DC648C02532928E89E72DC0'::geometry) + ((name <-> 'some name'::text) * '1000'::double precision)))
                     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on station a  (cost=0.00..50538.15 rows=33482 width=72) (actual time=9.623..2538.315 rows=26786 loops=3)
                           Filter: (coords IS NOT NULL)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 66.466 ms
 Execution Time: 3061.047 ms
```

Comment: You should explicitly say that the text `<->` operator is coming from pg_trgm (assuming of course that it is).

Answer (score 3):

Your query does not match your plan.  LIMIT 1 will not produce 10 rows.

If 24.70674, 43.1379 and 'some name' were always unchanged, I think you could create an index to optimize this ORDER BY.  But that seems exceedingly unlikely to be the case.  If those value change from execution to execution, you can't create an index to optimize this in its current form.

You could deploy some kind of heuristic, for example selecting all points within 50 miles, then sorting just that reduced set of points on the exact expression you want and applying a LIMIT.